# How do i grey out some stats in Google GeoChart that are not part of my alerting

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, solarwinds-orion

I am using Google visualization GeoChart to color code US states based on quantity network alerts by state. I get these alerts through Solarwinds Orion where i have a custom Attribute of all my nodes assigned to a State. When the node goes down, it triggers an alert, and the node's assigned state is also included. Problem i am trying to solve is that I some states that there are zero alerts for, which i can set to a default color of Green, but there are states that we do not operate in and I want those to be excluded from any color at all, and just have a deparate color of grey, null.

I added a link at the bottom to an image of my Geochart. for example. I have things in California but there are no alerts, so i want it to be green. But i do not have anything in Montana, so i want that state to show grey.
I have all the code working to paint the states that do have alerts triggered and I do have a "default" background color for any state with zero alerts except i cannot figure out the code to exclude certain states that we have no presence it at all that i want to be grey or null in color.

Here's my code...

```
    <!--Begin GeoMap code-->>
var swql="\
SELECT SUBSTRING(TOSTRING(DATETRUNC('Day',TimeStamp)),0,12) AS Day,\
COUNT(*) AS Qty,\
ISNULL(AlertHistory.AlertObjects.Node.CustomProperties.State,'Unknown') AS State\
FROM Orion.AlertHistory\
WHERE YEAR(TOLOCAL(TimeStamp)) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(TOLOCAL(TimeStamp)) = "+querymonth+ "\
AND\
DAY(TOLOCAL(TimeStamp)) = "+querydate+" AND EVENTTYPE='0'\
GROUP BY DATETRUNC('Day',TimeStamp),AlertHistory.AlertObjects.Node.CustomProperties.State\
ORDER BY DATETRUNC('Day',TimeStamp) DESC,QTY DESC"
                    
var params = JSON.stringify({
        query: swql,
        parameters: {
        }
    });
                        
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Orion/Services/Information.asmx/QueryWithParameters',
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.d.Rows);
                                
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart'],'mapsApiKey': 'MyGoogleAPIKeyRemoved'});
                                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    function drawRegionsMap() {
                    
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'State' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Qty' });
                                
                    
        for(var i=0; i < response.d.Rows.length; i++){
            var row = [response.d.Rows[i][2],response.d.Rows[i][1]];
            dataTable.addRow(row);
                                
        }
                                
        var options = {
            region: 'US',
            resolution: 'provinces',
            colorAxis: {colors:['yellow','red']},
            datalessRegionColor: '#AADAA6', 
            legend: 'none',
        };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
                            }
                    }
                })
<!--end GeoMap code-->>
```

Here's a snapshot of what it looks like now: [image]